# Drawing a rectangular shape with a border around it in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

Could anyone please tell me how do I draw a rectangular shape with a black border around it?

I want that for all my rectangles in the following TikZ picture:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {shape          = rectangle,
                                         rounded corners,
                                         fill           = black!30!white,
                                         minimum width  = 3cm,
                                         minimum height = 1.5cm,
                                         align          = center,
                                         text           = black},
                   black edge/.style  = { -,
                                         ultra thick,
                                         black,
                                         shorten >= 2pt}]

% the nodes : possible  \newcommand*\dx{5} \newcommand*\dy{2}
\node(0;0) at (5,0) {Patients};
  \node(1;1)  at (10, 2) {Treatment $A_1$};
  \node(1;-1) at (10,-2) {Treatment $A_2$};
\foreach \j in {-1,1}
  { \draw[black edge] (0;0.east) -- (1;\j.west); }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `draw= black` in the `every node` style.

Comment: The question is wrong. You want to draw a border with a node and with a rectangle's shape. It's not exactly a rectangle like with `(a,b) rectangle (c,d)`

Comment: Is `draw` (or `draw=black`) what you needed and wanted? Or do you actually want to draw two lines as in the answers below? `draw` just draws the border of a shape (here: a rectangular with rounded corners) and works for every node shape. Or do you want to draw a rectangle wit the path operator somewhere around the nodes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `draw,double=<color>,double distance = <dimen>` in `every node` style.:

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {shape          = rectangle,
                                         rounded corners,
                                         draw,                    %% here
                                         double=red,              %% here
                                         double distance =1pt,    %% here
                                         fill           = black!30!white,
                                         minimum width  = 3cm,
                                         minimum height = 1.5cm,
                                         align          = center,                                         
                                         text           = black},
                   black edge/.style  = { -,
                                         ultra thick,
                                         black,
                                         shorten >= 2pt}]

% the nodes : possible  \newcommand*\dx{5} \newcommand*\dy{2}
\node(0;0) at (5,0) {Patients};
  \node(1;1)  at (10, 2) {Treatment $A_1$};
  \node(1;-1) at (10,-2) {Treatment $A_2$};
\foreach \j in {-1,1}
  { \draw[black edge] (0;0.east) -- (1;\j.west); }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If you don't want color, use simple `double` instead of `double=<color>`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With PSTricks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\newpsobject{myrec}{psframe}
{
    border=2\pslinewidth,
    bordercolor=black,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](4,3)
    \myrec[linecolor=yellow](2,1.5)
    \myrec[linecolor=white](2.5,2)(4,3)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Border-lining on –1: a) PSTricks, b) rectangles in arbitrary/random places and c) not related to any of the elements resulting from OP’s code.